# Jquery dragging two classes together at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create my own timeline which has two separate divs with the same class. What I would like to do is group these two classes so they can both be dragged at the same time, no matter which one you select.

Reason for this, is because I will have one div which displays the timeline of the years, and another with the content for the corresponding years. So as you scroll from left to right, both elements must move together at the same time.

This is currently what I have...

HTML

```
<div id="timeline-container" class="col-sm-12">
    <div id="timeline" class="draggable">
        <ul class="years">
            <li id="first"><p>1900</p></li>
            <li><p>1980</p></li>
            <li><p>1990</p></li>
            <li><p>2000</p></li>
            <li><p>2010</p></li>
            <li><p>2020</p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="draggable">
        <p>This text needs to drag with the timeline</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    axis: 'x'
});
```

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/kze6bqzk/

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap both of those divs in a single "draggable" block.

This keeps the two content divs seperate which will allow you to use them in code as you see fit, however the wrapper "draggable" div ensures they are moved together.

```
<div id="timeline-container" class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="draggable">
        <div id="timeline">
            <ul class="years">
                <li id="first"><p>1900</p></li>
                <li><p>1980</p></li>
                <li><p>1990</p></li>
                <li><p>2000</p></li>
                <li><p>2010</p></li>
                <li><p>2020</p></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>This text needs to drag with the timeline</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kze6bqzk/2/)

Comment: I didn't think it was possible due to the complexity, but with some shuffling around and CSS tricks, I have managed it, so thank you very much. :)